# How can I return all the particular values from all documents in MongoDB using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

**The Question:**

How can I return all the particular values from all documents in MongoDB using Python?

**The Goal:**

What I want to do is return the all the matching values from all documents in python.

So the result I want using the below data set would be: `[Project0, Project0]`

**Sample Data set:**

```
id: idName0

ProjectName: Array
- 0: Project0
- 1: Project1

id: idName1

ProjectName: Array
- 0: Project0
- 1: Project2
```

**What I've tried and the result:**

```
request_data['searchValue'] = 'Project0'
check = users_collection.find({"projectName": request_data['searchValue']})
resultArr = list()
for item in check:
    print(item['projectName'])
    resultArr.append(item['projectName'])
```

But the result was only the first document and it returned `[Project0, Project1]`.

Comment: To return part of the document, use projection. Read the documentation for the find method.

Comment: Projection surpasses the keys returned but not the values. My problem is that MongoDB is returning all the values for a particular key.